# Make Downloader which download file in background and upading progressbar

Tags: android, service

I want to develop file downloader app . which download list of file .when I add file to downloader list then its updating progress periodically.
I close all activity and again I run the app then my app list all the current downloads with continuous progressbar

What should I do for that ?

I am using this async  task for downloading File

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
                int count;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                    conection.connect();
                    // getting file length
                    lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                    // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                            url.openStream(), 8192);
                    OutputStream output = null;

                    if (space_avaliable) {
                        File dir = new File(
                                Utill.saveFile(CustomGroupTabActivity.mTabHost
                                        .getContext()) + "/tocaonline");
                        if (!dir.exists()) {
                            dir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        // Output stream to write file
                        output = new FileOutputStream(
                                Utill.saveFile(CustomGroupTabActivity.mTabHost
                                        .getContext())
                                        + "/tocaonline/"
                                        + "test.mp3");

                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                        long total = 0;

                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;
                            // publishing the progress....
                            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                            publishProgress(""
                                    + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                            // writing data to file
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        // flushing output
                        output.flush();
                    }

                    // closing streams
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                // setting progress percentage
                p_bar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            }
        }
```

And when I click on add to download button then I am adding dynamic view to the linear layout.

```
LinearLayout lytParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.boxset_parentview);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(CustomGroupTabActivity.mTabHost
                .getContext());

        View convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_set_detail, null);

final ProgressBar p_bar = (ProgressBar) convertview
                .findViewById(R.id.rawsetdetails_sync_progress);

lytParent.addView(convertview);
```

It running well when my activity is active. but when I close all activity and again running this activity then I want to show actual downloading progress with active downloads.

Comment: Please find it in my edited question

Answer (score 3):

This how you can achieve it:

1) Run a background service for downloading. This [link](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/) gives you basics of service. It would use thread pool for multiple active download. It would read the data in chunks and send the chunk read event to register listener so that activity can update its UI.

2) Whenever you want to download, send the request to the service with item name, item id and the http link. Service would keep these three things for each download along with total size of download and the no of bytes downloaded.

3) Now whenever you launch the activity (lets call is download manager screen) then ask service to provide of current active and queued download. service would provide the list of download item(item name, item id, item http link, item total size and no of bytes downloaded) you can use this to create your view using the ListView. You can use the item total size and no of downloaded bytes for creating the progress bar.

4) Register for chunk read event with service. So service would notify the activity after each chunk read for download request with item name, item id, item http link, item total size and no of bytes downloaded. Use this info to update the item list in activity and notify adapter that data as been changed to it would update the list view.

5) Unregistered the event listener when the activity is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ListView. 
In that case you have to add Code in `getView()` like: 
If download running: show progressBar
Else: hide progressBar.

That is because Android re-uses the Views if possible and so maybe the View is still Visibile by mistake.

Comment: Thanx for answer, But when i close all activity and run again the same activity then  i want to show the previous downloading file with updating downloading progress. How i restore the all the data ?